# Comparar dois totais usando LEFT JOIN no MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas: `Venda` e `ProdutosVenda`, onde a tabela `Venda` tem um campo chamado 'Id_Chave' e a `ProdutosVenda`, que armazenará os produtos dessa venda, tem um campo chamado 'Id_Referencia', que é a referencia da venda nos produtos ('Id_Referencia' = 'Id_Chave').

Acontece que estou tentando somar os totais destes produtos para cada venda (`ProdutosVenda`) e comparar com o total da venda em si (`Venda`) para procurar inconsistências na tabela. Porém no código que eu fiz estou tendo o problema dele duplicar o resultado no lado da tabela `Venda` e isso não acontece se eu fizer duas consultas separadas.

Segue a minha query:

```
SELECT ProdutosVenda.Id_Referencia, SUM(Venda.TotalVenda), 
SUM(ProdutosVenda.Subtotal), 
IF(TotalVenda = Subtotal, "Igual", "Diferente")
FROM Venda
LEFT JOIN ProdutosVenda ON Venda.Id_Chave = ProdutosVenda.Id_Referencia
WHERE Venda.DataOperacao = '2017-05-04'
GROUP BY ProdutosVenda.Id_Referencia
```

Resultado:

```
Id_Referencia | TotalVenda | Subtotal | Meu IF

00000001.1    | 3400       | 3400     | Igual
00000002.1    | 3399.9     | 3399.9   | Igual
00000003.1    | 4368.64    | 2184.32  | Diferente ***
```

Acontece que no resultado que deu diferente ele duplicou o valor que seria esperado do TotalVenda, que seria 2184.32. Coisa que não acontece se eu fizer a consulta individual para essa tabela.

Obs.: Essa venda tem dois produtos, de 1092.16 cada e as outras vendas que duplicaram também tem mais de um produto.Já as que deram iguais na consulta tem apenas um produto.

Comment: Provavelmente está ocorrendo porque você tem `mais de 1 item em algumas vendas`, então o valor da `tabela Venda` repete conforme o número de registros da `tabela ProdutosVenda`. O que poderia fazer é fazer é fazer um select com GROUP BY ou DISTINCT somando os itens, e um select também com GROUP BY ou DISTINCT na tabela vendas, e fazer um UNION nas duas, assim teria os valores `1 para 1`.

Comment: Tentei fazer desse jeito que tu me falou porém ele parece que só me retorna o resultado do primeiro select e eu preciso que apareça os dois resultados na tela pra eu verificar se há diferença.

Comment: Vou postar na resposta um exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando há 2 tabelas (1 para muitos), você tem que partir da tabela que tenha mais registros relacionados, agrupá-los e referenciar com a tabela com registro único.

Select:

```
SELECT Id_Chave, TotalVenda, SUM(Subtotal) ValorProdutos, Id_Referencia
FROM ProdutosVenda PV
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendas VV ON PV.Id_Referencia = VV.Id_Chave
GROUP BY Id_Chave, Id_Referencia, TotalVenda
```

Select 2 (dessa forma fica 1 por linha):
Você fará um selet para venda e um para soma dos itens.
Juntar as 2 tabelas em 1 só, ordenar por ID.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT ID, VALOR, NULL, NULL FROM VENDAS)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL, NULL, ID_VENDA, SUM(VALOR) FROM PRODUTOSVENDAS
GROUP BY ID_VENDA)
) T_ALIAS
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Me retornou um erro: Duplicate column name 'NULL'

Comment: Cola seu select inteiro aqui

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT Id_Chave, TotalVenda, NULL, NULL FROM Vendas)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL, NULL, Id_Referencia, SUM(Subtotal) FROM ProdutosVenda
GROUP BY Id_Referencia)
) T_ALIAS
ORDER BY Id_Referencia

Comment: Testa assim: SELECT * 
FROM ( 
 (SELECT Id_Chave, TotalVenda, NULL Id_Referencia, NULL Produtos FROM Vendas) 
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT NULL Id_Chave, NULL TotalVenda, Id_Referencia, SUM(Subtotal) Produtos FROM ProdutosVenda GROUP BY Id_Referencia) 
 ) T_ALIAS 
ORDER BY Id_Referencia

Comment: Vou fazer um outro com join em linha

Comment: Até apareceram mas o segundo select só começou quando acabaram os registros do primeiro.

Comment: Já editei minha resposta, e postei encima. SALVO algum erro com relação tabela x campo sua. Mas o conceito está ai.

Comment: Consegui com o select em linha que tu me mandou, porém voltamos a estaca zero, pois o registros do TotalVenda somam duplicados quando há mais de um produto na venda.

Comment: Tem skype ? me passa se tiver.

Comment: Tenho sim: victorairesmm

Comment: Já te add, hora que quiser me chama lá. Mas cara, o 1o select ali, era para ter dado certo se realmente você tem todos registros da ProdutosVenda, com uma Venda, e vice-versa.

Comment: Cara, consegui resolver. O erro era meu, pois o campo TotalVenda é o valor total da venda, logo não existe nenhuma soma nele, somente no campo de Subtotal de Itens. Fiz a correção e funcionou certinho com o teu SQL. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Abração!

Comment: Opa, acabei de atualizar. Precisou tirar o SUM do TotalVenda, colocar no GROUP BY se não ele dá erro. Se está tudo ok. Marque como resolvida. Abraço.